# Change the sender address for google form response

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have this script for running an email response after the person submit it, is there a way to change the sender? Cause I saw that is related to the person who made de script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

var emailRecipients = e.namedValues[headers[7]] + "@google.com";
var emailSubject = "New holiday request";
var emailBody = "<h3>Hello "+e.namedValues[headers[7]]+", this a new vacation request by an agent </p>";

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emailRecipients,
  subject: emailSubject,
  htmlBody: emailBody
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The sender is always the person who created the trigger

If you want to change the sender your options are:

- Add an additional editor to the spreadsheet and let him create the `onSubmit` trigger - in this case this new editor will be the sender
- Use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) - this would allow you to authenticate as any domain user and send an email on his behalf
- Create a [delegate](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en) or an [alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) and send with the [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail) and email on behalf of the alias (sendAs) or delegate